# How to pass an EL variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

I have a variable `${bean.name}` how can i pass it to a javascript var? I've tried  `var name = "${bean.name}"`  and  `var name = ${bean.name}` but it does not work.

my idea is to put it in a hidden input like  in a hidden `<input id="test" type="text" value"${bean.name}">`

```
var name = document.getElementById("test").value;
```

this doen't work either `var name` becomes the string `"${bean.name}"`

note. i can't use jstl

Comment: are you trying to pass a JSON into JavaScript or something?

Comment: it works for me. ;) you must be more specific about how it doesn't work.

Comment: @KJY112 No i dont think its JSON

Comment: @Bozho it doesn't work as i my name variable becomes the string "${bean.name}" and not the actual value of bean.name

Comment: @Dave819 - are you putting the code into a static file (maybe a .js file?) that isn't being parsed by the JSP interpreter?

Comment: @Dave What is bean.name?

Answer (score 7):

You can't have JSTL evaluated in `.js` files. Only in `.jsp` files. (unless you remap the jsp servlet, but I wouldn't advise to do so).

The better approach is to define the variables in the .jsp including the .js, and pass these variables as arguments to an initializing function.

Also make sure you don't have `isELIgnored="true"`

Answer (score 4):

> *this doen't work either var name becomes the string "${bean.name}"*

Make sure that you're running a Servlet 2.4 capable container and that `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

This way EL will work in template text as well (without the need for JSTL `<c:out>`). It was namely introduced in Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0. Tomcat 5.5 is an example of a Servlet 2.4 container. If your container supports a higher servlet API version, e.g. 2.5 or 3.0, then you should declare the `web.xml` conform this version to benefit all newest features.

You'll then also be able to do the following in the JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var name = '${bean.name}';</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can using function [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) ,just like as follow:

```
var name = eval("${bean.name}");
```

if you want pass a JavaBean to a js var ,you should override toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

An example to Bozho suggestion, this way i worked facebook login.

***Scenario:***

I have a property in application.properties and i need this value in `facebook-login-sdk.js` initialize facebook login. So i read it in java `LoginController` via below code, then read it in `login.jsp` and assign a global variable `applicationFacebookId` then use this global variable in `facebook-login-sdk.js` file.

***IMPORTANT NOTE :*** Read variable name applicationFacebookId  before include facebook-login-sdk.js. Because you will use a global variable so you want to set it before facebook-login-sdk.js called.

***application.properties***

```
security.application.facebookId=yourApplicationFacebookid
```

***LoginController.java***

```
@Value("${security.application.facebookId}")
private String applicationFacebookId;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("applicationFacebookId", applicationFacebookId);
        return "login";
    }
```

***login.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var applicationFacebookId = '${applicationFacebookId}';
    //alert('applicationFacebookId:' + applicationFacebookId);
</script>
<title>Login Page</title>
<script src="<c:url value="/static/js/facebook-login-sdk.js" />"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

***facebook-login-sdk.js***

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : applicationFacebookId,
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
        xfbml : true,
        version : 'v2.7'
    });
```