# Expression language in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just wondering if it is possible to include `Expression Language` to a `jQuery`?I did try coding in `jQuery` like this: `$('#{data.data}').val();` and it seems work but I want to know if it is really possible because in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155885/how-to-pass-an-el-variable-to-javascript) the EL for him doesn't work.

So i really want to know the cases if it is really possible or there are some cases or settings for you to be able use `EL` in `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Balus answered this question in the link that you gave.  As long you are using greater than or equals to servlet 2.4

Comment: Is that only the case?

Comment: to quote "Make sure that you're running a Servlet 2.4 capable container and that web.xml is declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher."  I have never had any trouble using EL in jquery.

Comment: One last question, how about JSTL? like foreach tags can it be used with jQuery?