# Accessing the expression language in javascript of a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

I have a "jsp" file. In that file I have "Javascript" scripting.
Within `<script>` tags,only javascript is allowed but, how is "Expression Language" executed?

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var b=${requestScope.name};
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: you can check this detailed answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39355888/1577363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executed.

As "Expression Language" is executed on the server side the statement

```
${requestScope.name}
```

executed at server side and its value is available to JavaScript at client side. now at the client side the line becomes

```
var b='corresponding expression language executed value';
```

Answer (score 5):

bring that variable from request scope to page scope,

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="${request.myVar}" />
```

after this you can try this :

```
<script>
    var myVar= '${myVar}' ;
</script>
```

Though I am not sure if it's the best approach; but this should do.

Answer (score 3):

JSP is server side. You cannot access the script variables. These variables are only executed client-side.