# Rendering EL variables in externally linked javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, el

How do we resolve EL variables in linked javascripts? Is it possible? What are the options?

This is what I'm doing:

```
<a id="apiCaller" href="">API Caller </a>

<div id="returnData">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/api.js" ></script>
```

inside api.js: (where ${pageContext.request.contextPath} doesn't get resolved)

```
$("#apiCaller").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myAPI",
        success: function(returnData){
              alert(returnData.data);
            $("#returnData").empty.append(returnData.data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Answer (realized this is a related question): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158157/1435070**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally handle this in an inline script block included on every page.  Placing the context root in a global variable.  For example, to get the context root in my blog I use:

**base_js.jsp**

```
<script>
        var ttRoot = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" ;
</script>
```

This snippet is part of a fragment that is included on every page via a template:

```
<!-- Load Base Javascript Javascript -->
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/fragments/base_js.jsp" />
```

Then when constructing a url I use this global variable:

```
 var url = ttRoot + "/secure/resume/manager/skills/" + skillId + "/tags";
```

Comment: Neat. Thanks for the direction. I found a similar solution which I added to the question, but the base_js.jsp sounds like a cool idea! I've upvoted the responses to show my appreciation.

Comment: @chinmayzen I am glad I could help.  All my code is on Github if you want to check it out.  See: https://github.com/kmb385/ToThoughtWebLayer/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/fragments/base_js.jsp

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put the value of contextURL inside any span tag or hidden element.

```
<span id="contextUrl" style="display:none;">${pageContext.request.contextPath}</span>
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" id="contextUrl" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

And inside your JS get its value with its ID or Class attribute.

```
$("#apiCaller").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var contextURL = $("#contextUrl").text();
var formUrl = contextURL+'/myAPI';
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: formUrl,
    success: function(returnData){
          alert(returnData.data);
        $("#returnData").empty.append(returnData.data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I like this approach as well. I guess I will end up using a mix of a base_js and this one. Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, i'd stick to keeping js variables in script tags, to keep stuff where it belongs. Thanks for the answer though!