# Comparison of JavaScript Boolean variables in IF statements

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

In my Spring MVC project I am getting the one Boolean variable as a model attribute from the controller in my JSP view. based on the Boolean variable's value I have to execute the Js code. So I am comparing the value in the if statement. but it is not giving me the correct output:

The code is something like this:

In spring controller the Boolean variable is:

```
boolean isAdmin;
```

which is recieved by the JSP view and I can access it as follows:

```
$(isAdmin)
```

In my JSP view I am doing as follows:

```
<script>
  alert('${isAdmin}')  // which gives the correct value .i.e : true / false

  if('${isAdmin}'){

   // some code
  }

</script>
```

So in the above if statement if the value of the isAdmin is **false** than it should not be execute if block but it does executed even the value is **true**.

I also compared the value of the Boolean variable as follow:

```
if('${isAdmin}' == true )
if('${isAdmin}' === true)
```

But these both are also not working.

So correct me where I am doing the wrong? and what is the correct comparison method for this?

Comment: Use `'${isAdmin}' === 'true'`.

Comment: @alexmac Thank you. Your solution is correct.

Comment: The answer is in your question. You're wrapping it in single quotes, which means it's not `true` but `'true'`, which is text.

Comment: @ChrisG but without wrapping it in single quote gives compile time error

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, the reason  for the single quote is that EL expressions should be wrapped by quotes.

Comment: Can you show your js code after rendering?

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan No

Comment: maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155885/how-to-pass-an-el-variable-to-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the resulted value is a String and you are expecting a boolean,  `'${isAdmin}'` should be check against a boolean String value. As already someone commented, it should be `'${isAdmin}' === 'true'`.

```
if('${isAdmin}' === 'true') {
  // TODO
}
```

The reason why it is always executing is Javascript truthify the if expression. For example `if("false")` is evalutes to true and executes

```js
if("false"){
alert("What ??");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your scenario, you have a boolean variable `isAdmin` in the server side (JSP). You want to inject it in a javascript code, but it is not working, because you are creating a string literal instead of a boolean one:

```
if ('true') {
  console.log('This always executes');
}

if('false') {
  console.log('This always executes, too');
}
```

This happens because any non empty string is considered a "truthy" value by Javascript.Remove the quotes and it will work.
But for the sake of cleanliness, I would move the Javascript code to its own file and I will create a hidden field in the HTML code to store the `isAdmin` value:

```
<input id="isAdminFlag" type="hidden" value="${isAdmin}" />


if ($('isAdminFlag').val() == 'true') { ... }
```

Comment: Anyway in the end you checking against 'true'. Why not directly doing it and having extra input field ?

Comment: It's one of way injecting server side generated value in JS code,
Second way is using <![CDATA[   ]]>. It works with Theamleaf, I didn't tested  it in JSP

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the value without quotes?

```
if (${isAdmin}) {
```

Comment: Yes it gives the compile time error in <script> tag

Comment: @AkshayPethani, could you use `<%= ${isAdmin}) %>`?

Comment: @NinaScholz I tried this too. But it also not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your rendered js code is wrong. Rendering engine should put the value of 'isAdmin' in js code, but actually not doing.
You need to add your script like this

```
 <script>
<![CDATA[
     var isTrueSet = ('${isAdmin}'=== 'true');

      if(isTrueSet ){
          // some code
  }
]]>
</script>
```