# How to call a JS function by Bean JSF passing parameter as soon as the page loads?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf, web

I have to call a function in my JS by passing a vector as a parameter when the page loads.

I can do this using a p: commandButton, where here:

```
 actionListener = "# {routeEnterBean.GetMap ()}"
```

I run the function in the Bean (getting values in the database) and then, here:

```
 oncomplete = "initMap (xhr , status, args) "
```

Thus, the JS function is executed

Code Bean:

```
public void gerarMapa() {   
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addCallbackParam("coord", new 
          org.primefaces.json.JSONArray(coordenadas));
    }
```

Function JS

```
function initMap(xhr, status, args) {  
    var qtd_entregas = args.coord.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.coord.length; i++) {
        waypts.push({
            location : args.coord[i].latitude + ', ' + args.coord[i].longitude,
            stopover : true,
        });
    }
}
```

But I'm wanting to do this without having to click the button as soon as I load the page.

I know that it is possible to execute a function using this command:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("testeJS();");
```

But I do not know how to pass a vector as a parameter

Comment: Please read the answer by BalusC in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155885/how-to-pass-an-el-variable-to-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can **keep your existing code** and do it using Primefaces [p:remoteCommand](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) by adding following line on your page

```
<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" actionListener="#{routeEnterBean.gerarMapa()}" oncomplete="initMap(xhr, status, args);"/>
```

Attribute `autoRun="true"` will force `p:remoteCommand` to be executed on page load.